# iOS safari WebGL memory leak in iframe

Tags: safari, webgl

Test environment: iPad6 iOS 14

I have a sample html with a iframe in it.Each time the iframe switch from webgl page to blank,memory leak occurs.Repeat this safari will finally crash and reload.

Safari memory usage can be seen from perfdog(perfdog.wetest.net).Note: filter process to "com.apple.WebKit.WebContent".

Memory leak log:
[image]

Test iframe page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        /* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
        .column {
            float: left;
            width: 80%;
            padding: 10px;
            height: 600px;
            /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
        }

        .column2 {
            float: left;
            width: 20%;
            padding: 10px;
            height: 600px;
            /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
        }

        /* Clear floats after the columns */
        .row:after {
            content: "";

            clear: both;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        function htmlToElement(html) {
            var template = document.createElement('template');
            html = html.trim(); // Never return a text node of whitespace as the result
            template.innerHTML = html;
            return template.content.firstChild;
        }

        function createIframeIfNotExists() {
            let iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
            if (!iframe) {
                const deviceLostHtmlString = `
                    <iframe id="iframe" src="" width="100%" height="100%" title="Iframe Example"></iframe>
                    `;
                iframe = htmlToElement(deviceLostHtmlString);
                document.getElementById("iframe_parent").appendChild(iframe);
            }
            return iframe;
        }

        function toWebgl() {
            createIframeIfNotExists().src = "https://webglsamples.org/aquarium/aquarium.html";
        }
        function toBlank() {
            let iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
            if (iframe) {
                iframe.src = "about:blank";
                // iframe.contentWindow.document.write('');
                // iframe.contentWindow.document.clear();
                // iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
            }
        }
        function toGitee() {
            createIframeIfNotExists().src = "https://gitee.com";
        }
    </script>

    <h2>Two Equal Columns</h2>

    <div class="row">
        <div id="iframe_parent" class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
            <!-- <iframe id="iframe" src="" width="100%" height="100%" title="Iframe Example"></iframe> -->
        </div>
        <div class="column2" style="background-color:#bbb;">
            <button onclick="toBlank()">about:blank</button>
            <button onclick="toWebgl()">WebGL sample</button>
            <button onclick="toGitee()">gitee</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Update:

Webkit bug report: https://bug.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=218168

Comment: If you want to report a bug then go to https://bugs.webkit.org. If you want a workaround, first I'd make a smaller sample than the WebGL aquarium. Just create a webgl context and allocate twenty 1024x1024 textures or something. But otherwise have you tried removing the iframe and creating a new one instead of just changing it's source? Of course if that doesn't fix it then you're left with reporting the bug or figuring out if whatever you're trying to do can work without reloading the iframe or maybe run without an iframe.

Comment: I am having same issue. When I repeatedly reload my webgl microsite, memory just keeps piling up until crash & reload. Only if I terminate Safari, clear cache and then open microsite again, it works as expected. Any success in finding solution? @zombielei

Comment: @Siniša
Nope. According to bug report and test, it looks like a bug in Safari.